# Observer Design Pattern with using database

Tags: c#, java, sql, design-patterns

I m reading the book *Head First Design Patterns*. I understand perfectly why to use Observer Design Pattern, but my question is where to use it in real World?

Lets say I have **10000 subscribers** on my system and all users stored in a database, and 1 another subscriber wants to add itself to system so How can I implement this?

I dont think I will define a `List<>` and load all **10000 subscribers** in to my Subject class. So How I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are the most commonly used real world example of the Observer design pattern.